# Using user-defined color in VS Code own Color Theme

Tags: colors, vscode-extensions, color-scheme

In documentation of VS Code Extensions, it is mentioned that you can define your own color: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.colors

How can I use this color in the [Color Theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/color-theme#create-a-new-color-theme) I create?

For example, I have the following in **package.json**

```
"contributes": {
        "themes": [
            {
                "label": "My Color Theme",
                "uiTheme": "vs-dark",
                "path": "./themes/my-color-theme.json"
            }
        ],
        "colors": [
            {
                "id": "color.gold",
                "description": "Gold",
                "defaults": {
                    "dark": "#FFB71B",
                    "light": "#FFB71B",
                    "highContrast": "#FFB71B"
                }
            }
    ]
}
```

And the following in **my-color-theme.json** (I would like to use "gold" for one of the item but it does not work):

```
{
    "name": "My Color Theme",
    "type": "dark",
    "colors": {
        "editor.background": "#000000",
        "editor.foreground": "#FFFFFF",
        "sideBarTitle.foreground": "color.gold",
    },
    ...
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Color entries can only contain color values of the form `#RGB, #RGBA, #RRGGBB or #RRGGBBAA`, nothing else. No other color format (hsl etc.) or named color is supported. Hence `"sideBarTitle.foreground": "color.gold"` is an invalid entry.

Comment: It's what I was guessing but wanted to be sure. Thanks